# deference in restore back up sql and management studio

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have a SQL Server database backup file for a backup performed in SQL Server Management Studio.

When I restore it using SQL Server Management Studio, it restores to the point the back up was made; but restoring by command line would go to an unknown point, which I have to update.

My code is:

```
sqlCmd -E -S MYSERVER -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [MYDB] FROM DISK='C:\..\SQLSample.bak' WITH FILE=2, RECOVERY"   >> C:\..\restoreResult.txt
echo[ >> C:\..\restoreResult.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not to be rude, but what are you talking about? What does "restoring by command line would go to an unknown point, which I have to update" mean? You need to clarify what you expect and what you get instead that you would like to resolve.

Comment: Well in nutshell if restore in management studio it restore correctly. if used command line i get an old database.

Comment: I have taken many backups but in both cases using latest.

Comment: `WITH FILE=2` Looks like you might be choosing the incorrect file inside of the backup. This is a REALLY good observation of reasons not to use appending of backup files. Check the backup file headers and make sure you're choosing the correct one.

Comment: thx Sean, I got your clue, there are many files inside of the backup. file 1 is oldest file. When I used WITH FILE = n (n is the latest file number) it works

Answer (score -1):

```
sqlCmd -E -S MYSERVER -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [MYDB] FROM DISK='C:\..\SQLSample.bak' WITH FILE=2, RECOVERY"   >> C:\..\restoreResult.txt
echo[ >> C:\..\restoreResult.txt
```

this command go to last backup taking time. if you want to go point in time backup. you must take transaction log backup and then restore it.

Comment: Your code sample includes only the same code referenced in the OP.  If you have an answer to the problem, you should demonstrate that answer, rather than repeating parts of the question.